# Commutator length of the fundamental group of some grope

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

A popular way to describe a grope as the direct limit $L$ of a nested sequence of compact 2-dimensional polyhedra
$L_0 \to L_1 \to L_2 \to \cdots$
obtained as follows. Take $L_0$ as some $S_g$, an oriented compact surface of positive
genus $g$ from which an open disk has been deleted. To form $L_{n+1}$ from $L_n$, for each
loop $a$ in $L_n$ that generates the first homology group $H_1(L_n)$, attach to $L_n$ some $S_{g_a}$ by identifying
the boundary of $S_{g_a}$ with the loop $a$. Since the fundamental group of $S_g$ punctured
is a free group on $2g$ generators, this procedure embeds each $\pi_1(L_n)$, and thus
each finitely generated subgroup of $\pi_1(L)$, as a subgroup of a free group, with each
generator $a$ of $\pi_1(L_n)$ becoming a product of $g_a$ commutators in $\pi_1(L_{n+1})$. Hence
$\pi_1(L)$ is a countable, perfect, locally free group. See [What is a grope?](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Math/ewExternalFiles/what-is-teichner.pdf) for some motivation. The following is a schematic picture for building a grope in general.

[image]

Here we build a grope $A$ in stages.  At each stage put in disks with 3 handles on all the various handle curves at that stage. In other words, grope $A$ is built using disks with 3 handles uniformly throughout.

> **Question.** Is it possible that there is a generating set $S$ of $\pi_1(A)$ such
> that each element of $S$ have commutator length exactly 2?

Per the discussion with HJRW, I'm posting a related more general question.

> **Question.** Let $B$ be a grope built using disks with 2 handles uniformly throughout. Are there other methods of distinguishing the fundamental groups of $A$ and $B$? Even more general, are there methods of distinguishing gropes built using disks with $m$ handles and disks with $n$ handles, where $m \neq n$?

Comment: $G$ being the most standard notation for a group, I wouldn't use it for a generating subset of a group... Is it correct that you have the subgroup $\pi_1(A)\subset\pi_1(L)$, and, denoting $B_i(H)$ for the set of elements of commutator length $\le i$ in a group $H$, you're asking whether $\pi_1(A)$ is generated by $\pi_1(A)\cap B_2(\pi_1(L))$?

Comment: @Ycor Sorry, bad notation. I changed it to S. I shouldn't have used $A$ for a grope. Maybe I should use $L'$? In my question, I just want to specify a way to construct a grope following the general procedure in the first paragraph. That is, I want to use punctured genus 3 surfaces to build a grope.

Comment: I presume you mean bounded above? If so, isn’t the answer obviously “yes”: the abelianisation is trivial, so the group is perfect and the set of commutators (each of commutator length 1) generates.

Comment: @HJRW: You're right. I'll make the change.

Comment: @ShijieGue: Commutators in free groups satisfy relations (eg the Hall--Witt identity), so you certainly remove a single commutator and still generate the whole group. Surely you want a more natural condition?

Comment: @HJRW: I see. Thanks. What’s the best way to eliminate cases like those? What if I further require at least one element in S has commutator length 2?

Comment: I have no idea what the “best way” is! What’s the motivation for your question?

Comment: @HJRW: I'd like to distinguish the grope built using disk with 2 handles from grope A by looking at the commutator length. So I hope the commutator length can somehow reflect the geometric differences, i.e., disk with 2 handles and disk with 3 handles. I can just require each element in S has commutator length exactly 2. But I'm also interested in a mixture of commutator 1 and 2.

Comment: @ShijieGu: Oh, I see. I *think* the question with commutator length exactly two may be a good one. But there are certainly other methods of distinguishing their fundamental groups. Are you interested in them too?

Comment: @HJRW: Yes. I'm interested. I'll add another question. I would be grateful if you could share your ideas.

Comment: It will take me a few days to find time to write this out, but I have in mind distinguishing the two groups using JSJ decompositions. Basically, the obvious graph-of-groups structure on the fundamental group given by the construction is canonical. See the monograph by Guirardel--Levitt for details. https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05139

Comment: @HJRW: Thank you. I'll take a look.